# Subscription Library Software - Email and Web Based Access to PDF Library

Tags: web-development, subscription

I'm looking for a piece of software, and was going to post on SO but I think it would be better here since it isn't specifically a programming question.

I know I could custom program this, but would rather not re-invent the wheel. The company I work for has a publication that is published weekly, in paper format. We now receive it in PDF format so that we can begin distributing it digitally. I am looking for some web software, preferably PHP/MySQL, that would do the following:

1. Allows subscribers to **sign up and manage** their subscription online. This would handle renewals, payments (either via CC processor, paypal, etc).
2. When we receive the issue from the printer (in final PDF), we would **e-mail** it out to the subscribers. It can either be done as a PDF attachment or a link in the email so that they can download it.
3. An **online archive** would allow members to log in and **download** past versions of this publication.

It seems like something like this would exist but I haven't found anything (or my google queries aren't formed right!). If I can't come up with one piece of software that does this, I might resort to a combination of a "member" site with a library and then use existing email software to notify members there is a new download available for them.

Free or paid solutions acceptable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds highly similar to a software distribution model - sell the software, allow payers to get previous versions, and have a convenient email database to easy automate sending.

You can look at [VirtueMart](http://virtuemart.net/), a powerful ecommerce solution, based on Joomla, that is very, *very*, customizable (including payment gateways).

Either that, or you can go for [OSCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I've used both VirtueMart and OSCommerce pretty extensibly. Their 'software download' module would work for for one-off downloads however since this is a 'subscription' I don't think they would work well without extensive modifications. I also looked into Magento but same capability is lacking.